# PNG-images turn blank/corrupted after build and archive

Tags: ios, xcode, png

I ran into a strange problem today, after renaming a couple of images in my app and making sure they work on a device as well as the simulator, I used Build and Archive as I always do to build my app to distribute to the testers.

However, this time I got strange reports from the testers saying the images were gone, so I installed the build on my phone and to my surprise they were gone as they said. Tried to do a clean and build again but no change.

When I open the .app archive I can clearly see that many, but not all, of the images have turned blank, they appear to be the same physical size on the disk and they also seem to have the correct height and with when I press space to preview them, I can't however open them with photoshop for example (the file-format module cannot parse the file).

This is very confusing and as I have to get the build ready for testing very soon I would very much appreciate some help in this matter.

Comment: try to remove them..run on device..add them ..and then run again..The problem is quite an unusual problem..dont know if this is a bug..

Comment: Turning off PNG-compression in xcode does seem to work, I still don't understand why this happens though, is this the only way?

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported to Apple

Comment: Concerning the unability to display them on a machine, have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1681/_index.html Apple uses a customized version of `pngcrush` which generates output that seems to be unreadable by some applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source PNGs seem to be slightly off-standard or at least incompatible with Apple's pngcrush. Make sure you use a commonly well functioning tool for creating the PNGs - when in doubt reconvert/resave them.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happened to my images still, but I believe this is the correct answer after all so I'll mark it.