# 4/40 pngs dont show up?

Tags: ios, png

I have two buttons that the user can select the colour for. The left button has 20 png to choose from, the user can select the colour from a picker and then that colour is displayed in an example button in the view, all 20 work fine. Now the right button has another 20 BUT only 16 of them work? 4 of the pngs wont show up in the example button or in the actual button they are set to on another view. The pngs are the same size as the others, the same in every way except colour. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen?

I do get this error when building onto the device : ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

Comment: put some relevant code here :)

Comment: Why don't you double check name of images and name when you are using those images. Or if condition you are passing is returning `TRUE` to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a compatibility issue similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929693/png-images-turn-blank-corrupted-after-build-and-archive?rq=1)

I had used PS to make all the images but when I open them and resave in PaintBoard then they seem to get picked up now?

Upon further inspection it looks like the size has reduced greatly as well now as PS was saving a whole heap of other information with each image. I will go through them all now and resave them just to make the program more economical.